# Xcode wont let me see selected or highlighted syntax.

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, syntax-highlighting

Lately I have been trying to copy and paste some code around in xcode but for some odd reason, the editor doesnt show what I highlight or select and its really frustrating. The copy and paste works but I can see what I am highlighting. I dont know if this is an xcode settings issue or something else. Please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these steps:

1. Goto XCode->Preferences.
2. Under Font & Colors, See the "Selection" under "your choosen theme".
3. Adjust the selection color as per your need and you are good to go. The RGB for default selection color is 167, 202, 255 respectively.

Comment: dude! Run for president. Id totally vote for you! yOu the man!